# how to clean some character from row in mysql?

Tags: mysql, dynamic-sql

How to remove some part of rows from column in mysql? I have a column like this

[image]

my desire output is like this

[image]

Comment: GIGO.  The best time to deal with such is to split up the data _before_ inserting it.

Answer (score 1):

Fairly easy with a couple of string functions ... change test to the name of your table of course.

```
update `test` set bfi_name = substr(bfi_name,instr(bfi_name,' ')+1)
```